# Spring security and EJB

Tags: java, spring-security, ejb, cdi

I am trying to set up a roles user authentication system via spring security in an EJB application.
I implemented UserDetailsService as follows:

```
@Stateless
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Inject
private UserDAO userDao;
...
}
```

UserDAO :

```
@Stateless
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{

@PersistenceContext(name="persistence-unit-name")
private EntityManager em;
...
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Inject
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
...
}
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends 
AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
    super(SecurityConfiguration.class);
  }
}
```

When I deploy my project, I have the following exception:

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 24 more
```

Why can not inject UserDetailsServiceImpl into SecurityConfiguration? Any Ideas to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Because `UserDetailsServiceImpl` isn't declared as a Spring bean? `@Stateless` doesn't work with Spring, you need `@Component` or one of the others

Comment: I Tried using `@Component` in `UserDetailsServiceImpl` and autowired it with `@Autowired` in `SecurityConfiuration`,  but still got the same Exception.

Comment: Any idea for autowiring my service?

Comment: Are you sure? If you get the same exception after annotating it with the Spring annotations, you probably have some component scanning issues. Are you scanning the correct packages for spring bean when creating your application context?

Comment: Oh and by the way, your `UserDaoImpl` needs to be spring annotated as well, since you're injecting it's interface as well

Comment: It's an EJB+CDI project that contains three modules: Model, Service and Web.  All the services and DAO classes are annotated with `@stateless`.
I'm trying to use Spring security in the web module.